# How to pass params into a Factory for object creation?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory

I have `RecipientTypesFactory` that is going to create objects of the type `RecipientType`. For `RecipientType`s object I have the followin hierarchy:

```
public interface RecipientType{
    public abstract Object accept(RecipientTypeVisitor v);
}

public class DynamicGroupType implemetns RecipientType{

    private Integer dynamicGroupId;

    public Object accept(RecipientTypeVisitor visitor){
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
    //GET, SET
}

public class StaticGroupType implements RecipientType{

    private Integer staticGroupId;

    public Object accept(RecipientTypeVisitor visitor){
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
    //GET, SET
}
```

`RecipientTypesFactory` itself looks as follows:

```
public enum RecipientTypeEnum {
    STATIC_GROUP, DYNAMIC_GROUP
}

public class RecipientTypesFactory{
    private Map<RecipientTypeEnum, RecipientTypeCreator> creators;

    public RecipientType createRecipientType(RecipientTypeEnum t){
        return creators.get(t).create();
    }
}
```

I'm not going to provide the actual definition of `RecipientTypeCreator` and its hierarchy because I don't think it's very important.

Now I have the controller:

```
public class CreateMailingController{
    private RecipientTypesFactory recipientTypesFactory;
    private Integer dynamicGroupId;
    private Integer staticGroupId;
    private RecipientTypeEnum selectedType;

    //GET, SET, other staff

    public void createMailing(){
        Type t = recipientTypesFactory.createRecipientType(selectedType);
        //How to initialize t's field with an appropriate value?
    }
}
```

The thing is `RecipientTypesFactory` and its `creators` know nothing about `CreateMailingController`'s `dynamicGroupId` and `staticGroupId` values. Those values are setting up by some user from web-interface. Therefore the factory cannot initialize the corresponding field of a type to create with these values.

`RecipientTypesFactory` and its creators are spring beans.

***Question***: How can I pass the values of `dynamicGroupId` and `staticGroupId` to the Factory in a flexible way and avoid wiriting `switch-case` like code? Is that possible?

Maybe there's another patter for that purposes. In fact the factory is creating the prototype of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to avoid switch cases,like below:

```
private static final Map<String, RecipientType> factoryMap = Collections
            .unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, RecipientType>() {
                {
                    put("dynamicGroupId", new RecipientType() {
                        public RecipientType accept() {
                            return new DynamicGroupType();
                        }
                    });
                    put("staticGroupId", new RecipientType() {
                        public RecipientType accept() {
                            return new StaticGroupType();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

    public RecipientType createRecipientType(String type) {
        RecipientType factory = factoryMap.get(type);
        if (factory == null) {

        }
        return factory.accept();
    }
```